# How to resolve javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException issue?

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, smtp-auth

I am doing a `sendMail` `Servlet` with `JavaMail`. I have `javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException` on my output. Can anyone please help me out? Thanks.

sendMailServlet code:

```
try {
        String host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        String from = "my@gmail.com";
        String pass = "pass";
        Properties props = System.getProperties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
        props.put("mail.smtp.user", from);
        props.put("mail.smtp.password", pass);
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.debug", "true");

        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
        Address fromAddress = new InternetAddress(from);
        Address toAddress = new InternetAddress("test1@gmail.com");

        message.setFrom(fromAddress);
        message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, toAddress);

        message.setSubject("Testing JavaMail");
        message.setText("Welcome to JavaMail");
        Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
        transport.connect(host, from, pass);
        message.saveChanges();
        Transport.send(message);
        transport.close();

    }catch(Exception ex){

        out.println("<html><head></head><body>");
        out.println("ERROR: " + ex);
        out.println("</body></html>");
    }
```

Output on GlassFish 2.1:

```
DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "smtp.gmail.com", port 587, isSSL false
220 mx.google.com ESMTP 36sm10907668yxh.13
DEBUG SMTP: connected to host "smtp.gmail.com", port: 587
EHLO platform-4cfaca
250-mx.google.com at your service, [203.126.159.130]
250-SIZE 35651584
250-8BITMIME
250-STARTTLS
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250 PIPELINING
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SIZE", arg "35651584"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "8BITMIME", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "STARTTLS", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "PIPELINING", arg ""
STARTTLS
220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
EHLO platform-4cfaca
250-mx.google.com at your service, [203.126.159.130]
250-SIZE 35651584
250-8BITMIME
250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250 PIPELINING
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SIZE", arg "35651584"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "8BITMIME", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "AUTH", arg "LOGIN PLAIN"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "PIPELINING", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Attempt to authenticate
AUTH LOGIN
334 VXNlcm5hbWU6
aWpveWNlbGVvbmdAZ21haWwuY29t
334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6
MTIzNDU2Nzhf
235 2.7.0 Accepted
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc]
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
```

Comment: when does the exception occurs exactly ? I can't see it in your logs

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to implement a custom [`Authenticator`](http://java.sun.com/products/javamail/javadocs/javax/mail/class-use/Authenticator.html)

```
import javax.mail.Authenticator;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;


class GMailAuthenticator extends Authenticator {
     String user;
     String pw;
     public GMailAuthenticator (String username, String password)
     {
        super();
        this.user = username;
        this.pw = password;
     }
    public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication()
    {
       return new PasswordAuthentication(user, pw);
    }
}
```

Now use it in the [`Session`](http://java.sun.com/products/javamail/javadocs/javax/mail/Session.html)

```
Session session = Session.getInstance(props, new GMailAuthenticator(username, password));
```

Also check out the [JavaMail FAQ](http://java.sun.com/products/javamail/FAQ.html)

Comment: @n002213f : How do I use this GMAILAuthenticator when I am obtaining the session from mailservice.xml from a jndi call(jboss).

Comment: @Ashwin - take a look at the answer to a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3475971/configure-the-mail-service-xml-in-jboss-with-a-gmail-account

Comment: @n002213f : you gave a brilliant solution,Now I'm implementing this just replace smtp gmail server to my own smtp server name,but getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/mail/Authenticator error(as I'm implementing it with the help of jsp/servlet )...any inputs..

Comment: Great answer, but I prefer the second (Uma's answer). My authenticator worked, but Google's standards are (fortunately) too strict. Still, +1.

Comment: I am facing the exact same issue, tried this and the second answer. Neither is working for me, I am using tomcat as web container.

Answer (score 20):

This error is from google security...
This Can Be Resolved by Enabling Less Secure .

Go To This Link : "https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps" and Make "TURN ON" then your application runs For Sure.

Comment: Oh, tq :) . I have Struggled for this for so much time. This should not happen to any One . so, I made it Clean and Clear Phil C

Comment: It works for me but how to make it work without having to allow less secure applications to use IMAP?

Answer (score 2):

I was missing this authenticator object argument in the below line

```
Session session = Session.getInstance(props, new GMailAuthenticator(username, password));
```

This line solved my problem now I can send mail through my Java application. 
Rest of the code is simple just like above.

Answer (score 1):

When you are trying to sign in to your Google Account from your new device or application you have to unlock the CAPTCHA. 
To unlock the CAPTCHA go to https://www.google.com/accounts/DisplayUnlockCaptcha
and then [image]

And also make sure to [allow less secure apps on](https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps) 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, you are creating a `transport` object and using it's connect method to authenticate yourself.
        But then you use a `static` method to send the message which ignores authentication done by the object.

So, you should either use the `sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients())` method on the object or use an authenticator as suggested by others to get authorize
         through the session.

Here's the [Java Mail FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes), you need to read.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to share with you:
I happened to get this error after changing Digital Ocean machine (IP address). Apparently Gmail recognized it as a hacking attack. After following their directions, and approving the new IP address the code is back and running.