# Configure the mail-service.xml in JBoss with a Gmail account

Tags: email, jboss, gmail

I want to configure my mail-service.xml to send emails from my Gmail account. I have made a configuration, but it doesn't work

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<server>
  <mbean code="org.jboss.mail.MailService"
         name="jboss:service=Mail">
    <attribute name="JNDIName">java:/Mail</attribute>
    <attribute name="User">***@gmail.com</attribute>
    <attribute name="Password">***</attribute>
    <attribute name="Configuration">
      <configuration>
        <property name="mail.smtp.auth" value="true"/>
        <property name="mail.smtp.starttls.enable" value="true"/>
        <property name="mail.smtp.socketFactory.class" value="javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory"/>

        <!-- Change to your mail server prototocol -->
        <property name="mail.store.protocol" value="pop3"/>
        <property name="mail.transport.protocol" value="smtp"/>

        <!-- Change to the user who will receive mail  -->
        <property name="mail.user" value="nobody"/>

        <!-- Change to the mail server  -->
        <property name="mail.pop3.host" value="pop3.nosuchhost.nosuchdomain.com"/>

        <!-- Change to the SMTP gateway server -->
        <property name="mail.smtp.host" value="smtp.gmail.com"/>

        <!-- The mail server port -->
        <property name="mail.smtp.port" value="465"/>

        <!-- Change to the address mail will be from  -->
        <property name="mail.from" value="nobody@nosuchhost.nosuchdomain.com"/>

        <!-- Enable debugging output from the javamail classes -->
        <property name="mail.debug" value="false"/>
      </configuration>
    </attribute>
    <depends>jboss:service=Naming</depends>
  </mbean>

</server>
```

Comment: Please tick the correct answer from these

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I struggled with this too, but eventually got it working.  I wrote up what I did here:

http://mrmcgeek.blogspot.com/2010/09/confguring-java-mail-with-jboss-as-5.html

You need to add the following to the mail-service.xml:

```
<property name="mail.smtp.user" value="${username}@gmail.com" />
<property name="mail.smtp.password" value="${password}" />
<property name="mail.smtp.ssl.enable" value="true" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't set the host properly.Try this one

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- $Id: mail-service.xml 62350 2007-04-15 16:50:12Z dimitris@jboss.org $ -->
<server>
<mbean code="org.jboss.mail.MailService"
 name="jboss:service=Mail">
<attribute name="JNDIName">java:/Mail</attribute>
<attribute name="User">type sender mail id here</attribute>
<attribute name="Password">type password</attribute>   
<attribute name="Configuration">
<!-- A test configuration -->
<configuration>
<property name="mail.smtp.auth" value="true"/>
<property name="mail.smtp.starttls.enable" value="true"/>
<property name="mail.smtp.socketFactory.class" value="javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory"/>
<!-- Change to your mail server prototocol -->
<property name="mail.store.protocol" value="pop3"/>
<property name="mail.transport.protocol" value="smtp"/>

<!-- Change to the user who will receive mail  -->
<property name="mail.user" value="nobody"/>

<!-- Change to the SMTP gateway server -->
<property name="mail.smtp.host" value="smtp.gmail.com"/>

<!-- The mail server port -->
<property name="mail.smtp.port" value="465"/>
<!-- Change to the address mail will be from  -->
<property name="mail.from" value=""/>

<!-- Enable debugging output from the javamail classes -->
<property name="mail.debug" value="false"/>
</configuration>
</attribute>
<depends>jboss:service=Naming</depends>
</mbean>
</server>
```