# Email send failed using commons email library

Tags: java, email

```
 try {
        Email email = new SimpleEmail();
        email.setHostName("smtp.googlemail.com");
        email.setSmtpPort(587);
        email.setAuthenticator(new DefaultAuthenticator("***@gmail.com", "*********"));
        email.setSSL(true);
        email.setFrom("*******@gmail.com");
        email.setSubject("TestMail");
        email.setMsg("This is a test mail ... :-)");
        email.addTo("*****@gmail.com");
        email.setTLS(true);
        email.send();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

This is the code I've used and this is the print stack trace

```
org.apache.commons.mail.EmailException: Sending the email to the following server failed : smtp.googlemail.com:587
    at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.sendMimeMessage(Email.java:1242)
    at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.send(Email.java:1267)
    at Main.main(Main.java:28)
Caused by: javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:306)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:156)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:105)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:168)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:98)
    at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.sendMimeMessage(Email.java:1232)
```

can someone tell me what's wrong with my code??

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2047942/how-to-resovle-javax-mail-authenticationfailedexception-issue

Answer (score 0):

Did you try on [port 465](http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=78799) ?

And with [email.setSSLOnConnect(true);](http://commons.apache.org/email/userguide.html) instead of setSSL and setTLS ?