# How to send mail using Simple Java Mail framework?

Tags: java, email

I use Simple Java Mail framework for sending mail.
I read documentation there - [simplejavamail.org](http://www.simplejavamail.org/#features).

My code:

```
Email email = new Email();
        email.setFromAddress("SomeOne1", "someone1@aol.com");
        email.setSubject("Newsletter");
        email.addRecipient("SomeOne2", "someone2@aol.com", Message.RecipientType.TO);
        email.setText("Some text");
        email.setTextHTML("there my html");

        new Mailer("smtp.aol.com", 587, "testjavasimplemail@gmail.com", "hunter2", TransportStrategy.SMTP_TLS).sendMail(email);
```

But now I have error:

```
июн 25, 2015 6:30:47 PM org.codemonkey.simplejavamail.Mailer sendMail
SEVERE: null
javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:319)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:169)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:118)
    at org.codemonkey.simplejavamail.Mailer.sendMail(Mailer.java:242)
    at pkg.Main.main(Main.java:39)

Exception in thread "main" org.codemonkey.simplejavamail.MailException: Generic error: null
    at org.codemonkey.simplejavamail.Mailer.sendMail(Mailer.java:250)
    at pkg.Main.main(Main.java:39)
Caused by: javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:319)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:169)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:118)
    at org.codemonkey.simplejavamail.Mailer.sendMail(Mailer.java:242)
    ... 1 more
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Are you using your actual details when you run this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to resolve javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException issue?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2047942/how-to-resolve-javax-mail-authenticationfailedexception-issue)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the wrong SMTP server. You need the GMail one.

```
"smtp.aol.com" -> "smtp.gmail.com"
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using an gmail account to connect to an aol smtp server !

Try with the good parameters ...